# Navbar is not working when resizing the browser windows on one WordPress theme and after adding the JS code mobile menu close button is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying a WP theme but when I'm resizing the browser windows size then the mobile menu is not working but in the same small windows after refreshing the browser page the menu is working.

As I don't know much about coding so if anyone can have a look and help me :)

Here's the link of that demo theme: https://demo.wptravelengine.com/travel-booking/

Someone helped me with this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
jQuery("#toggle-button").click(function() {
    jQuery(".site-header .right").css("right","0");
})
jQuery(".btn-close-menu").click(function() {
    jQuery(".site-header .right").css("right","-540px");
}) })
```

But when I am using this code, it is not showing the close icon button and search form holder when opening it after resizing the web browser screen.

see the pic here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Il3UT1Wehcg0nAyCfW2smVSbdpCwPS0b/view?usp=sharing

Apart from that, when I am opening the site in the normal mobile close icon is not working after opening the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your compiled js code I see that its wrapped in a condition so that the click does not fire unless the screen is less than 1024px. This check only fires onload so that is why you have to refresh when resizing the browser window (you have to load the window smaller than 1024).  You need to add a function to check on resize as well:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
// run same 1024 check to allow click after resizing to avoid having to refresh
});
```

Comment: I've added it but when resizing the screen the close button and search form holder is not showing in the mobile view.